Firebase core error occur during debugging
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:. Required by: project :app
try all ai ,youtube but unable to solve my problem

have you added firebase core dependencies in your project?

I hope you have a credible reference of doing it from official Firebase for Flutter - if Android.
